# Variance and bias

Tags: error

Consider the mean squared error $$\text{MSE}(x_0) = E_{T}(f(x_0)-\hat{y}_0)^{2}$$ $$ =  E_{T}(\hat{y}_0-E_{T}(\hat{y}_0))^{2}+(f(x_0)-E_{T}(\hat{y}_0)^{2})$$

Is the first term after the equal sign in the second line basically saying the following: Get an estimate and find its deviation from the average estimates over all training samples. The estimate $\hat{y}_0$ will depend on the training set which is why we take the expected value.

Also is $E_{T}(\hat{y}_0)$ constant?

Comment: You probably mean $MSE(y_0)$, not of $x_0$. Also, not sure what the expectation $E_T$ stands for -- what is the probability space over which you are integrating? Is your $x$ random or fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Your intuition seems right, but for clarity, I would rewrite your equations as follows,

\begin{align}
\text{MSE}(\hat{y}) 
 &= E\left[(y-\hat{y})^2\right] \\
 &= \underbrace{E\left[(\hat{y}-E[\hat{y}])^2\right]}_{\text{Var}[\hat{y}]} + \underbrace{(y-E[\hat{y}])^2}_{\text{Bias}^2}
\end{align}

Here $y$ is the actual value of whatever we are estimating, and $\hat{y}$ is its estimator (the value of $\hat{y}$ will depend on the data).

The first term is the variance of the estimator (which is more or less what you said). Also, $E[\hat{y}]$ is non-random (this may be what you meant by constant).